# NFT Collection Ranking through Opensea API

Tags: nft, opensea

I am going to get NFT collections order by total_volume.

```
https://opensea.io/rankings?sortBy=total_volume
```

It is possible to get assets, but I cannot find proper api for that as there is no option for order by, it will be only fetch by created date.

Comment: How you managed to do this?

Comment: Actually, I didn't find a good solution, as any platforms don't like to share their own apis like that. :/ even I tried to fetch from the graphql query from opensea directly.

Comment: I needed to build my own apis and store info to my db as well.

Answer (score 0):

They use `?search[attribute]` as params. This is what I have seen.

So try something like this:

```
https://opensea.io/rankings?search[sortAscending]=true&search[sortBy]=TOTAL_VOLUME
```

Comment: I don't think its not possible to get JSON list through this url /: